# ADT/Eclipse won't start after uninstalling SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I was prompted to update SDK to v23 by ADT, but the update failed. So I tried a suggestion to uninstall and reinstall the Android Developer Tools from About > Installation Details.

But now ADT won't even start after uninstalling!

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I had exactly the same thing myself today and had to start over and  download a new copy of eclipse. Hopefully someone will provide a better solution than this for the future.

Comment: @user2145222 thanks. that's what I ended up doing.